# Removing space atop relatively positioned elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three subdivs within a larger container on my webpage. I need each of these three divs to be positioned directly below each other, and the top div to be placed directly at the top of the container. I need to use relative positioning as each div has a variable height in practice so absolutely positioning them is not applicable (however I have thought about dynamically using AngularJS here), however all three have a minimum height. For some reason simply using relative positioning leaves space of the container on top of each subdiv. How can I remove this space?

Here I have included a similar code example to the real thing:

```css
#wrapper {
  background:lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#top {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  background: red;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#middle {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  background: black;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#bottom {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  background: brown;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="top">
        <p>
        test
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="middle">
        <p>
        test
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="bottom">
        <p>
        test
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've researched this quite a bit, and the only answer I have found is to use absolute positioning.. However I cannot, because I cannot set a static top value as the divs have dynamic heights. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `margin` on the `<p>` element is causing the space.

You can target the first `<p>` in every `<div>` and remove it. Use `padding` instead if you want to have some distance from the top of the div.

```css
#wrapper {
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#top {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#middle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#bottom {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: brown;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

div>p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
      <p>
        test
      </p>
      <p>
        I still have a margin top
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
      <p>
        test
      </p>

    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
      <p>
        test
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Right, so it's only the topmost element causing the issue? If I were to have, say, 3 <p>'s within each div, I'd be able to use padding/margins on the bottom two? Right now on my site, elements within each of the divs need padding in order to look correct. I suppose I could relatively position each element, but the padding was much easier, especially with making the site dynamic.

Comment: In the example you've posted, only the top margin of the first `<p>` is causing an issue. Removing it should be all you need. Relative positioning is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

I think `overflow: auto;` is what you would like to have:

```css
#wrapper {
  background:lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
}

div{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto; /* add this*/
}

#wrapper div{
  position:relative;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#top {
  background: red;
}

#middle {
  background: black;
}

#bottom {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="top">
        <p>
        test
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="middle">
        <p>
        test
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="bottom">
        <p>
        test
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to remove the space in between the divs?
I think resetting the CSS will solve it like this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
#wrapper {
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#top {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#middle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#bottom {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: brown;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
      <p>
        test
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
      <p>
        test
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
      <p>
        test
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```